# RSS feed to external

Tags: html, rss

I am looking for a way to set up my own RSS feed. I want to be able to post something on my website (either locked to me, or via notepad), but I also want it to post this feed onto facebook and twitter.

Is there a novice way to set this up, or is this a feat better resolved by purchasing some software?

My bad attempt at setting up an rss feed that I would update by notebook is as follows (though I haven't got this working as temporarily intended):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">


<channel>
    <title>First post title</title>
        <link>http://www.mysite.com</link>
    <description>I'm posting a lot of words to fill in this space for my first potential rss feed, let's hope it works!</description>
        <atom:link href="http://www.mysite.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

<item>
    <title>Or maybe this is the first title</title>
    <link>http://www.mysite.com/page.html</link>
    <pubDate>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 16:50:32</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.mysite.com/page.html</guid>
    <description>This is potentially the first post or perhaps the second post of the new feed being create.<description>
</item>


</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feed has a couple of issues, namely an invalid date and a missing closing tag for the item description. Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>

    <title>First post title</title>
    <link>http://www.mysite.com</link>
    <description>I'm posting a lot of words to fill in this space for my first potential rss feed, let's hope it works!</description>
    <atom:link href="http://www.mysite.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

    <item>
      <title>Or maybe this is the first title</title>
      <link>http://www.mysite.com/page.html</link>
      <pubDate>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 16:50:32 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.mysite.com/page.html</guid>
      <description>This is potentially the first post or perhaps the second post of the new feed being create.</description>
    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

If you are creating feeds manually, then you can validate your markup with the [W3C Feed Validator](http://validator.w3.org/appc/#validate_by_input).

There are many ways you could automate this but impossible to provide a recommendation without knowing how you are currently generating your website content.

Comment: Apologies for the extended delay upon replying here, Passkit and thank you very much for tweaking my code.

Comment: (Damn, enter isn't a new line haha) my site is sn0wy0wl.com and I can provide you with code-source privately if this will make it easier in resolving a better way to generate this.

Comment: Looking at your source, it seems that you are manually building your pages.  This usually means you to need to build your own code to automate your feeds, although you may want to look at [http://www.rsspect.com/](http://www.rsspect.com/)

Comment: Correct, I'm manually building my pages, thank you for directing me to rsspect, I think I will try this out, meanwhile are there any recommended site in which to guide me constructing my own code?

Comment: There are so many!  If you are just starting out, then you might want to research MVC methodology.  Here is a short [tutorial](http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction) that outlines the main concepts and there are dozens of other PHP MVC references you can google.  Also don't forget to accept and upvote answers if you find them helpful - the more courtesy you give the community, the more you'll find they help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time once more PassKit, and thank you for being 'noob-friendly'! as you noticed, I am indeed just starting out and you've given me plenty to work with here.